# Mass find and replace with a Bass Script in PHP Application

Tags: php, regex, bash, grep

In a Zend Framework 2 application, there are 8/9 modules. In these modules, the View has over 15 odd phtml pages with hard coded links like

```
href='/controller/action'
```

What I need to do is build a bash script which will go through the modules look for places in which the view has the href above and change it to look like this

```
href="<?php $this->url('controller'), action->'action' ?>"
```

Comment: So build it. It you will have concrete questions - we will help. Otherwise -sorry.

Comment: show us that you've tried something

Comment: That's understandable, thanks for the comments. So what I tried was to get everything from the project that references the href="/controller/action" and outputted the contents into a file. I found 1500 odd lines of code. I tried to use Bash in which I tried searching the file with cat and called a function like search_href () {
cat $1 | wc -l
}. I really am not sure how to do this and in college doing work placement. Answer isn't needed if ye don't want to but some guidance would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the modules attaining the filenames and then:

```
 sed -r "s%href='/(.*)/(.*)'$%href=\"<?php $this->url('\1'), action->'\2' ?>\"%" filename
```

s%original text%replacement text%

Use -r to enable the interpretation of regular expressions

Make sure that you escape the quotation marks in the replacement text with \

Use (.*) as place holders for the dynamic text and then refer to them as \1 and \2 in the replacement text.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand that throwing question up here might look like the lazy way out in asking for the solution. I will try this but do you know of resources to get better at this?

Comment: Would the controller and action need to be hard written into the replacement text controller and action or would that be dynamic?

Comment: Not the original solution no. You didn't make that clear. The amended solution takes account of dynamic variables.

Comment: No, I didn't, sorry about that. I'm trying this now in a bash script and using the file I got all the hrefs from. Thank you for your time, Raman.

Comment: Okay, I've tried your fine answer, I copy and pasted it into the terminal and added my file to the end. The terminal printed out all the lines in the file. When I checked one area which the bad link is it didn't seem to change. Is there something wrong I might be doing?

Comment: We would need some examples of the dynamic lines then.

Comment: So the line that I'm trying to change is it? href="/ppdg/ppdg-record" would need to change like above. There is lines like href="/ppdg/ppdg-record?type=D&day=<?php echo $day;?>&batchNumber=<?php echo $this->escapehtml($foo->BATCH_NUMBER);?>"><?php echo $this->escapehtml($foo->BATCH_NUMBER);?> but I feel If I can get the first working I can do the rest.

Comment: Hey Raman, hope you are able to just help with one more thing. Those dynamic symbols don't seem to work for me. I tried using them and then also tried using the normal text like 'controller' and 'action' and the normal text version works fine. I can't crack the dynamic side. If I gave you say three links href="/cont/act" and href="/control/action" href="/controller/action" how would I use those dynamic symbols to reach all the links? Thanks for any time you have!

Comment: This is what i used for it to work with the static values... sed -i 's%href=\"/controller/action%href=\"<?php echo $this->url(\"controller\", action-> \"action\") ?>%g' changes.txt

Answer (score 0):

Some text editors can do the job otherwise for command, I would use

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec perl -i.bak -pe \
   'BEGIN{$str=shift;$rep=shift}s/\Q$str\E/$rep/g' \
   'href='\''/controller/action'\' \
   'href="<?php $this->url('\''controller'\''), action->'\''action'\'' ?>"' \
   {} +
```

This command should be adapted: see `man find` for options

Comment: Thank you Nahuel, I really appreciate the help. I have no knowledge in this and did try to research. I understand why some people might want to see proof of work first. I'll give this a shot. Do you recommend any resources to learn to get better?

Comment: type in google, otherwise autodocumented programs typing `-h` `--help` `man` `info` `help`.